# TokensRegex - using a group captured inside an annotation as an argument to the Annotate function

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to augment the results of the out-of-the-box NER related to dates.

For example, the phrase "the prior year" gets the NormalizedNER annotation of "THIS P1Y", which is clearly wrong.
It needs to be "PREV_IMMEDIATE P1Y".
Actually, I located the TokensRegex rules in "english.sutime.txt" that cause this.

I am trying to make this correction by applying the following extraction TokensRegex rule downstream:

```
{
    ruleType:   "tokens",
    pattern:    ( /the/ /prior/ [ {ner:"DATE"} & {normalized:/THIS (P\d\w.*)/} ]+ ),
    action:     ( Annotate($0, "normalized", "PREV_IMMEDIATE " + $$1.text) ) }
```

I have two issues with this rule:

1. I can't find the right syntax to combine a literal string with a capture group variable in the last argument to the Annotate function. The above "action" field causes the following exception:

   edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.parser.ParseException: Encountered " "+" "+ "" at line 34, column 72.
   Was expecting one of:
   ")" ...
   "," ...

   Apparently, the last argument is not casted to a String properly when I use the "+" to append strings together.
   What is the proper way to combine Strings in the last argument to the Annotate function?
2. Using "$$1.text" by itself as the third argument to Annotate gives me the following exception:

   WARNING: Error extracting annotation from the prior year
   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

   This should give me the text of the capture group "(P\d\w.*)".
   But it does not seem like the group is being captured.
   Is that because capturing a group inside an annotation (as opposed to inside the token text) is simply not supposed to work?
   Or am I doing something wrong?

In general, if these two problems cannot be solved directly, what is an alternative?
Producing a custom version of "english.sutime.txt" and making the OOTB annotators use it?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for pointing out that "prior" should be regarded as referring to the previous time.  We will add this to our rules as well.  For adding "prior" to the SUTime rules, the simplest thing would be to change:

```
{ pattern: ( /this|the/ /past|previous|last/ ),
  action: Tag($0, "TemporalOp", PREV_IMMEDIATE) }
```

to:

```
{ pattern: ( /this|the/ /past|previous|last|prior/ ),
  action: Tag($0, "TemporalOp", PREV_IMMEDIATE) }
```

If the `PREV_IMMEDIATE` doesn't work out, you can try to change it to `PREV`.  The intention is that `PREV_IMMEDIATE` and `PREV` act as operators on the following time expression to get the "previous" or the "past" occurrence of that time expression, but the `PREV_IMMEDIATE` operation is not well tested.  These operators are applied in a later rule:

```
{ name: "temporal-composite-6b",
  priority: 4,
  pattern: ( ( $REL_MOD ) ( [ $hasTemporal & !{ temporal::IS_TIMEX_SET } ] ) ),
  result: RelativeTime( GetTag($1[0], "TemporalOp"), $2[0].temporal.value )
}
```

As for your questions about TokensRegex syntax,

1. It's not possible to append strings in the `rules` file with `+` since the syntax doesn't actually support the full set of java operators.

To concatenate two strings, you need to use do `Concat(str1,str2)` instead of `str1 + str2`.  See http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ling/tokensregex/types/Expressions.html  for more operations supported by TokensRegex.

2. When working with TokensRegex, there are two types of capture groups.  Capture groups for TokensRegex, and capture groups from matching string patterns using the normal Java patterns.

`/THIS (P\d\w.*)/` is a Java string pattern.  In TokensRegex, `$1` is used to refer to the sequence of nodes captured by TokensRegex for TokensRegex capture group 1.  To get access to inner capture groups (like those from Java string patterns), the syntax `$$1` is offered to acces the `SequenceMatchResult` for the capture group.

To get access to those, you will need to set `matchWithResults` to `TRUE`.

```
{
  ruleType:   "tokens",
  matchWithResults: TRUE,
  pattern:    ( /the/ /prior/ [ {ner:"DATE"} & {normalized:/THIS (P\d\w.*)/} ] ),     
}
```

Then, you can access the match for `(P\d\w.*)` using
`$$0.matchResults[2].normalized.group(1)`. `$$0` gets the whole capture group from TokensRegex.  The `matchResults[2]` gets the matchResults for the token at index 2.  The `normalized.group(1)` gets the capture group for the Java string expression corresponding to the normalized annotation.

Note that this pattern won't actually work in SUTime since the `normalized` field is populated by NER after SUTime has gone through all the rules.

Comment: Hi Angel. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: The Concat() function I just missed in the Javadoc, so it was my bad. Setting the `matchWithResults` was a little less obvious and it does affect the `$$n.matchResults` population. Unfortunately, in my case `$$0.matchResults[2].normalized.group(1)` still evaluates to NULL for some reason. I tried to simplify the expression to `$$0.matchResults[2].word` and it also gives me NULL. Interestingly, `$$0.matchResults[0].word` returns "true" and `$$0.matchResults[0].normalized` returns the literal "null". I am confused. Aren't these expressions supposed to return the token text and NormalizedNER val?

Comment: `$$0.matchResults[0].word` and `$$0.matchResults[0].normalized` are returning the embedded Java String capture match results.  Whether it returns anything will depend on the whether you are using string patterns to match those fields.  If you want to get the matched token, you can use `$0[2]` and then you can use `$0[2].word` or `$0[2].normalized` to access the token text and NormalizedNER val.

Comment: Angel, my remaining problem is that `$$0.matchResults[2].normalized.group(1)` evaulates to NULL. This is what you advised me to use and it is consistent with the documentation (thanks for pointing out the need to use the `matchWithResults` field). If my use case is set up correctly then it looks like a bug. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: I have the same issue -- internal groups are not captured.